# Python 3.3 how to update a function's local namespace from another function's local namespace?

Tags: python

I have study several similar questions, but seems like no same question as mine. Below `update_namespace_from` is to update y's local namespace with x's local namespace.

How? or is it possible?

```
def x():
    a=1
    b=2
    c=3

def y():
    a=6
    d=4
    update_namespace_from(x())
    return a,b,c,d  # will get 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: What is the practical use of this?

Comment: @thefourtheye I am lazy to assign varibles in g() function like:a,b,c = f() when f() already has a, b, c variables processed

Comment: the references in `x` only exist during execution of it. So why not passing them or - if not avoidably - make use of global vars (not recommendable)?

Comment: If variables need to be shared between `x` and `y`, you should probably define a class and make the two functions methods.

Comment: @chepner Thank you. I should consider a Class

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use `global`, though this not suggested:

```
In [306]: def x():
     ...:     global a, b, c
     ...:     a=1
     ...:     b=2
     ...:     c=3
     ...: 
     ...: def y():
     ...:     global a, d
     ...:     a=6
     ...:     d=4
     ...:     x()
     ...:     return a,b,c,d  # will get 1,2,3,4

In [307]: y()

Out[307]: (1, 2, 3, 4)
```